# Is there any to detect closing of a tab or refresh event on a tab in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-listener

I'm using `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.confirmLeave);` where confirmLeave looks like this

```
 confirmLeave(ev){
  if(this.changesHandler({},true)){
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.returnValue = "";
  }
 }
```

but unload event fires even if block is not executed

till now i'd also used pageHide & visibility API but i guess they dont detect this scenario

Comment: sorry i don't understand the question do you mean it doesn't stop the user from leaving?

Comment: Only thing you can do is set it to make it prompt the user, you can not keep the user from leaving and there is no way to know what action actually is causing the page to leave. If the message is not appearing are you sure that changesHandler is returning true in a synchronous manner?

Comment: Basically this.changesHandler is comparing some changes if there is someChange it returns true else it returns false but in above case even if i try to refresh the page and changesHandler is false the prompt which says changes not save get fired which dont need to .

Comment: you can try calling `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.confirmLeave.bind(this))`